# Where does Umbraco store feeds/rss?

Tags: rss, umbraco

Do Umbraco sites have feed/rss fils for news content? (I am doing some work, which requires communication with the website, where the website owner has told me that the news content should be exposed as a RSS feed, but I can't locate it so... My guess is there's no RSS/feed contrary to what I am told, but as I don't know Umbraco, I may be mistaken.)

Answer (score 3):

Umbraco doesn't expose an RSS feed by default. You will need to either expose one yourself via a template/macro/view or use a package, such as [EyeCatch RSS Feed Generator](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/eyecatch-rss-feed-generator).